# Is every prime number less than twice the previous prime number?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

And if so, how do you prove it? (for example 7 is less than 2 times 5, 11 less than 2 times 7, and so on).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate

Comment: No, 2 is prime, 3 is prime, but 3 is less than 2*2

Comment: That's an example, not a counter-example, @Blex.

Comment: I edited the title of your post for clarity, please check that I didn't misunderstand.

Answer (score 4):

This is a Postulate([Betrand's)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) which says for every $n>3$, you can find a prime $p$ such that $n<p<2n$.

So, yes. If you any $n=p$, you can find prime $q$ such that it is less than $2p$.

At a very young age of $17$(As my guide says), Erdos' gave the most elementary proof to this. About which you can read [here](http://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/pdf/bertrand.pdf).

Comment: Hi, and that postulate was proved by Chebyshev? Is there a proof online? Actually my question is weaker than the postulate because I am requiring n to be prime.

Comment: @user79303 The two questions are essentially equivalent: if each prime is less than twice the next, then it's easy to prove there is a prime in any interval $[n,2n)$.

Comment: Erdos' [proof](http://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/pdf/bertrand.pdf) is a marvel.

Comment: @Inceptio, thanks for link!

Answer (score 2):

> Chebyshev said it, and I say it again - There is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$.

N. J. Fine's description of Erdos's new proof of Betrand's postulate.